# each item in an array into each matched element

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, loops, each

I am using $.getJSON to return a simple array such as:

```
["5","10","15","20"]
```

I then want to prepend each of these values to an element. I understand how to iterate through the array and perform a function, such as:

```
$(data).each(function(i,data){      
 console.log(data);         
});
```

What I can't figure out is how for each item in the array to add it to each matched element such as:

```
$('#element h2').each(function(){   
    $(this).before('<h1>' + data + '</h1>')
});
```

What I'm hoping to achieve is:

```
<div id="element">
  <h1>5</h1>
    <h2>Apples</h2>
  <h1>10</h1>
    <h2>Oranges</h2>
  <h1>15</h1>
    <h2>Bananas</h2>
  <h1>20</h1>
    <h2>Kiwis</h2>
</div>
```

Thank you for anyone that can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the index:

```
$('#element h2').each(function(index) {   
    $(this).before('<h1>' + data[index] + '</h1>')
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, makes total sense but I couldn't get there without help. I appreciate it very much.